90's horror/thriller, switchblade, sewers and head *in* a fridge
I'm looking for a horror film made presumably in the 90's when I was growing up. I can't remember much, so it's hard to look for.. Anyway, what I remember most is the female lead finding her friend's head in her fridge/freezer. I think a few of her friends got murdered by some creepy guy who lives in a lair of sorts and wanted to kill her too, I guess.. I remember being afraid of toilets and sewers for a while, he either lived there or was washed out there in the end. He had a switchblade-sorta knife. It would go in and out quickly and was scary as shit. There was some scene with the killer and lead in his bed, where the knife was shown. I don't remember any other "specific" details.
I need to find this and don't know how to look. Help.

Is this a "horror" flick of the "slasher" variety?

I know the movie you are talking about. I'm also looking for the name. One of the girls names was Melanie. I'm pretty sure it was her head in fridge. This was not Stephen Kings 'it'

Lots of elements you have mentioned match up with Stephen King's IT.
The school bad guy (Henry Bowers) carried a switchblade. IT lived in the local sewer system.
One of the good guys (Stan Uris) is murdered, with his head being found in a small fridge. The scene is shown here:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RnrlXmTiWCc
There is also a scene showing Henry Bowers in bed in an asylum, and I think the switchblade is shown.
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099864/

While rather unlikely at the first sight, when thinking about it this answer makes quite some sense.

Plus it's from 1990 which also fits.
